# Use rar.exe to create an archive file, how to name it accord to the original file?

Tags: winrar

I have a file named `windows tutorial.pdf` and its size is 140M. I use the `rar.exe` command from `WinRAR` to archive it.

```
rar.exe a -v50m archive.rar "windows tutorial.pdf"
```

The upper code will create a list of files.

```
archive.part01.rar
archive.part02.rar
archive.part03.rar
```

My question is, it there an easy way to specify the archive file name using the original file name (instead of specify it directly in the command like `rar.exe a -v50m "windows tutorial.rar" "windows tutorial.pdf"`)? In this case, what I want is

```
windows tutorial.part01.rar
windows tutorial.part02.rar
windows tutorial.part03.rar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a little batch file to do this for you.

Just create this file with a `.cmd` or `.bat` extension:

```
rar.exe a -v50m "%%~n1.rar" %%1
```

Then, run it with the file as a parameter:

```
myrar.cmd "windows tutorial.pdf"
```

`%%1` is the first parameter passed to the batch file.  The `~n` prefix makes the variable return only the filename, without the extension.  For more information on this behavior, [see this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215501/batch-remove-file-extension/3215539#3215539).